# Heroku deploy error; precompiling assets failed (noting line in devise.rb)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, heroku, deployment, devise

I have what appears to be a working application on my local machine with google_oauth2 and github oauth implemented. But when I push the master to Heroku it is rejected with an error stating that precompiling of assets failed (and indicating a problem with devise.rb). So, I ran precompile of my production environment locally and that completed *without error*. So then I ran precompile on Heroku and received an error. I am stumped.

Here are relevant portions of the log showing the push of master to Heroku rejected:

```
remote:        Bundle completed (1.76s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Installing node-v12.16.2-linux-x64
remote: -----> Installing yarn-v1.22.4
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
...
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
remote:        /tmp/build_ae858012/config/initializers/devise.rb:276:in `block in <main>'
remote:        /tmp/build_ae858012/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/devise-4.7.2/lib/devise.rb:307:in `setup'
remote:        /tmp/build_ae858012/config/initializers/devise.rb:11:in `<main>'
...

remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to aristutor.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/aristutor.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/aristutor.git'
```

Here are relevant portions of the log (with trace) when I tried to precompile assets on Heroku (after successfully precompiling locally):

```
Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
rabs-MacBook-Pro-2:lms rab$ heroku run RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile --trace
Running RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile --trace on ⬢ aristutor... up, run.1642 (Free)
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke yarn:install (first_time)
** Invoke webpacker:yarn_install (first_time)
** Execute webpacker:yarn_install
yarn install v1.22.4
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
...
remote:        Bundle complete! 39 Gemfile dependencies, 99 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into `./vendor/bundle`
remote:        Removing bundler (2.0.2)
remote:        Bundle completed (1.76s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Installing node-v12.16.2-linux-x64
remote: -----> Installing yarn-v1.22.4
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
remote:        /tmp/build_ae858012/config/initializers/devise.rb:276:in `block in <main>'
remote:        /tmp/build_ae858012/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/devise-4.7.2/lib/devise.rb:307:in `setup'
remote:        /tmp/build_ae858012/config/initializers/devise.rb:11:in `<main>'
```

I just yesterday got the omniauth working for google_oauth2 and github signin. It all appears to be working on my local machine. **Importantly, I was able to successfully push to Heroku when I commented out the following lines in devise.rb** (but I don't know what about those lines is causing the assets to fail to precompile on Heroku):

```
  config.omniauth :github, Rails.application.credentials[:github][Rails.env.to_sym][:client_id], Rails.application.credentials[:github][Rails.env.to_sym][:client_secret], scope: 'user,public_repo'
  config.omniauth :google_oauth2, Rails.application.credentials.dig(:google_oauth2, :client_id), Rails.application.credentials.dig(:google_oauth2, :client_secret), {}
```

**Edit**: I just discovered it is the second line (the :google_oauth2 line) that is causing the problem. With it commented out, the push to Heroku is successful.

I don't believe there is any error in retrieving the client id's and secrets - I tested those statements in the rails console and they returned the correct values.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked rails console with production environment? :D

Comment: Yes. And, I just discovered that it is the second line (config.omniauth :google ...) that is causing the problem. When it was commented out, push to Heroku succeeded. When first line commented out, same error. I'll edit my post to update that.

Comment: Interesting, do you notice that method to get the value of credential is  difference between 2 line

Comment: Yes, but let me conform them again and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Are you sure it's the google auth line? The error is what I'd expect when you're dereferencing a nested hash and a parent key is missing. I just plopped your code into an app of mine (without creating matching keys). The google_oauth line fails silently, but the GitHub line gives the same error you are seeing.

Comment: No, I am not sure. I now think I have problems with both lines. It will upload to Heroku successfully with only the google_oauth line, but signin fails with a "missing client_id' error. The "github line" causes the failure to precompile error.

Comment: Thanks both of you. I started reexamining why Heroku might not be getting the keys. It turns out that you have to manually set the master_key in Heroku settings. I did not know that. I spent all day working on this. I'm glad to have it working but it was a huge waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

I had failed to set the master key in Heroku environment variable settings.